# How to autmate "devmgmt.msc" / Device Manager

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I am currently attempting to automate a program like `devmgmt.msc`, or the Device Manager, in order to assist in my job at the "Tech Desk" in my school. Some issues I found are in there, and a quick uninstall/update/install quickly fixes it. However sometimes it becomes a pain. So now I ask, how can I automate it?

I'm not necessarily picky about the programming language, so I'm okay with whatever is suitable. However, if it is not possible to program that, is there another way?

What I'm trying to do:

```
devmgmt.Audio(Microphone).uninstall; 
if !devmgmt.Audio(Microphone).exists {devmgmt.Audio.scanForChanges}
```

If possible, please tell me how/what programming languages are required. Whether I could ideally use Java, or Batch/VBScript, etc.

Comment: Please post your batch-file attempts in a Q&A method.

Comment: I have used a microsoft utility called devcon.exe in scripts in the past for this purpose.

Comment: I'll try devcon.exe. Thanks.

Comment: What programming language is that code in your question?  Does not look like vbscript or Windows .bat file to me.

Comment: @Squashman Most likely pseudocode to illustrate (in a way) what he's trying to do.

Comment: WMI used to be a good resource.  Specifically, the wmic.exe command that ships with Windows can be run from batch/shell scripts.  There's WMI API's for C/C++ and .NET as well.  [SuperUser ](https://superuser.com/search?q=WMI) is probably a better venue for questions regarding WMI and its tooling.